# Angular radio element $invalid property not set when model value not in available options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I am running into a problem that if a model value to radio control is set which is outside the available options, The ng-required validation do not mark the element as $invalid. Is there any way to force the model value to be one of the available options?

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/mOCBrp?p=preview)

In this example, if I initialize the model value to `white` which is not available in the options, the element stays valid which I do not want.

This is just an example and I am having various such radio/selection lists, so I am looking for a generic solution which doesn't really depend on a particular set of model/values.

Thank you

Comment: Your setup is simply invalid. "generic" solution is to fix this logic mistake.

Comment: By generic I meant I always want to make sure the model value corresponds to a valid input element and flag the input invalid otherwise. Would you still consider it a mistake? :)